# Problem getting data from json through http with riverpod

Tags: json, flutter, riverpod

I have this json:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": -3.7026,
        "lat": 40.4165
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 800,
            "main": "Clear",
            "description": "clear sky",
            "icon": "01n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 297.84,
        "feels_like": 297.62,
        "temp_min": 294.82,
        "temp_max": 299.94,
        "pressure": 1017,
        "humidity": 48
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 1.34,
        "deg": 270,
        "gust": 2.68
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "dt": 1631051279,
    "sys": {
        "type": 2,
        "id": 2007545,
        "country": "ES",
        "sunrise": 1630993686,
        "sunset": 1631039875
    },
    "timezone": 7200,
    "id": 3117735,
    "name": "Madrid",
    "cod": 200
}
```

with this link:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3117735&appid=899fc742471c1a7623a573d0bc7ad85b

I want to get the data, to make that I created the class with a json convert, and get want to get the data through a json.decode:

```
 Future<Madrid> fetchMadrid() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3117735&appid=899fc742471c1a7623a573d0bc7ad85b'))
      .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return parseMadrid(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Error');
  }
}

Madrid parseMadrid(String response) {
  var list = json.decode(response);
  Madrid photos = Madrid.fromJson(list);
  return photos;
}

final madridStateProvider = FutureProvider<Madrid>((ref) async {
  return fetchMadridLocal();
});
```

and get the data through a Future Provider with riverbed.
I get the error: Expected a value of type 'Coord', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

Comment: share your model

Comment: Share your `Madrid` model.